# Random multiple image wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, random, product

How to random four product (image, name, price)  from 10 product in resource when windows_load. Help me, i'm newbie[image]

Comment: please post your resource file here instead of image

Comment: We actually don´t need your res-file but some short code-sample that show what you´ve tried already.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="_1660544.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_1660544"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="648" Width="958.5" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="47,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="/Picture/1.jpg"></Image>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PROSPAN" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 14000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="261,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/2.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TYLENOL" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 15000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="475,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/3.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ACC" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 16000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="689,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/4.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DOLIPRANE" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 17000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="47,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/5.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="THIOCODIN" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 18000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="261,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/6.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DẠ DÀY MEDI" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 14000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="475,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/7.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PANADOL" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 14500đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="689,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/8.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="BLACKMORES" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 14000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="47,418,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/9.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="MIDASOL" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 13000đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sp10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" Margin="261,418,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Image Height="127" Source="Picture/10.jpg"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="GARLIC" Height="28"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Giá: 19500đ" Height="28"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: apologies for not understanding but your XAML looks fine for what it is. What are you expecting it to do and where is it failing?